# What happens in the case of nearest neighbour interpolation OpenGL centre of pixels

Tags: c++, opengl, nearest-neighbor

What happens when a nearest neighbour interpolation occurs where the pixel for which the nearest neighbour interpolation is being calculated in texture is at the same distance from two neighbouring pixels, and the pixel falls equal distance in length from the two pixels that it is trying to correctly interpolate for a new pixel in the case of magnification.

Does OpenGL take the two pixels and interpolate a colour from the texture by taking an average value from the two at same length distance or something else happens?

Comment: Your question is a contradiction. If you're using `GL_NEAREST`, then the value of the pixel will be the nearest one. It will *not* be interpolated; that's what `GL_NEAREST` *means*.

Comment: okay fine i used the wrong words, but question still remains what happens when there is two nearest pixels both of same distance from the pixel that is to be filled from surrounding pixels?

Comment: I guess the question is what exactly happens on border cases: Assuming a 2 texel width texture, which texel will be choosen for lookup coordinate of 0.5.

Comment: @looking4answers: "*okay fine i used the wrong words*" Then fix the wording of your question to make it clear what you're asking for. There's a convenient edit button there for you to do so.

Answer (score 4):

The [spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf) is very clear about how texels are selected from a texture coordinate:

**Minification**

Section 8.14 specifies the minification behaviour (I skip here a lot of things regarding wrap modes etc. and explain the 2D case):

> Let [s(x,y), t(x,y)] be the texture coordinates at screen position (x,y). Now we define u(x,y) = s(x,y) * texture_width and v(x,y) = t(x,y) * texture_height. In case of nearest neighbor interpolation, the texel is given by the integer coordinates (i,j), where i = floor(u(x,y)) and j = floor(v(x,y)).

Lets do an example: Assuming we have a texture of size 2x1 and a lookup position of [0.5, 0.5]. In this case u(x,y) = 0.5 * 2 = 1 and v(x,y) = 0.5 * 1 = 0.5. Now we get i = floor(1) = 1 and j = floor(0.5) = 0. So, the result will be the color of the right texel.

**Magnification**

Section 8.15 states the the magnification behaves exactly as the minification.